# how to define html classes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have serval div's with classes and I want to define them in javascript.
Here is my jsfiddle script, It's only using DIV ID now but it has to be classes because I want to Add multiple blocks.
Can someone help?

```
var block = document.getElementById('block');
var minimizewindow = document.getElementById('minimizewindow');

block.style.height = "250px";
minimizewindow.style.display = "none";  

//function minimize
minimize.onclick = function(){
    if(block.style.height == "250px") {
        block.style.display = "none";
}   .........
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uVSyX/

click on the broken images for : minimize, maximze, close

Thank you!

EDIT : Think I don't get it, I wan't to show and hide multiple div's...

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are looking for but using `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementById` might help you.

Comment: `and I want to define them in javascript.` why? Why not define the style in a CSS style sheet, and then manually assign a class?

Comment: I want to make some look a like interface so I want to add new div's/classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');` is the easiest way, however it is not supported by IE.  [Mozilla has great documentation on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName).

If you need IE support, this page might be a good resource for you: http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getElementByClassName'  ... is the error I get

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer?

Comment: You misspelled it. it's `getElementsByClassName()` not `getElementByClassName()` - plural elements.

Answer (score 1):

> and I want to define them in javascript.

this is a bad idea. Styling instructions belong in CSS style sheets.

The right way to go here would be having classes, like `.expanded` and `.contracted`

They would contain rules like

```
.expanded { width: 800px; display: block }
```

you then just change the `class` property in JavaScript. jQuery makes this *very* easy because it has convenient methods for dealing with classes.

- http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/
- http://api.jquery.com/addClass/
- http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember where I found this function at but it's what I've used to find elements based on class.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),i;
for (i in elems) {
  if((" "+elems[i].className+" ").indexOf(" "+matchClass+" ") > -1) {
    elems[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

with `matchClass` being the name of the class you are looking for.

---

I updated the above code to set all `div` with a specific class that is defined as `matchClass` to be set to `display:none` when the function is run.

Comment: Think I don't get it, I wan't to show and hide multiple div's